# Find / Replace Directory and Bash Script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

I have some paths like this:

```
/www/site1.dev/public_html/test.htm
/www/site2.dev/html/test.htm
/www/site3.dev/public/test.htm
```

I'd like to pass them to a bash script and get a result back in this format:

```
http://site1.dev/test.htm
http://site2.dev/test.htm
http://site3.dev/test.htm
```

I'm not sure what the best way to handle the regex part of this is:

```
#!/bin/sh

RET='';

function trim() { echo $1; }


for ARG in "$@"
    do
        //do match and add existing RET value
        RET= 'http://'(regular expression or find/replace here) RET 
done


echo ">>$(trim $RET)<<"
```

**Solution**

My code based on Wes Hardaker's answer

```
        DOMAIN=`echo $ARG | sed 's#.*www/##'`
        DOMAIN=`echo $DOMAIN | sed -E 's#/(public|html).*##'`
        POST=`echo $ARG | sed -E 's#.*html##'`
        echo 'http://'$DOMAIN$POST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use 'sed'.  IE:

```
RET="http://"`echo $ARG | sed 's#/www##;s#/(public_|)html/#/#;'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the regular expression works? What is www##;s#? Also, what if the path has additional unknown characters before /www/ ?

Comment: sed allows for regular expressions that aren't based on using / characters, and thus you can use # characters to bound expressions that may contain lots of /s instead.  Thus, the first regexp *s#/www##* replaces /www with nothing.  The second, *s#/(public_|)html/#/#* replaces either */public_html/* or */html/* with /.

Comment: I didn't deal with additional items before /www/ since they weren't in your examples.  But you could add more to the filter expression: s#/foo/bar/path/to/www## would work too.

Comment: While all of the solutions on this page are good, I think using `sed` worked best for me. I added my syntax to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your paths are in a file

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}{print "http:/"$1,$3,$NF}' file
http://site1.dev/test.htm
http://site2.dev/test.htm
http://site3.dev/test.htm
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -F"/" -ane 'print "http:/"+[$F[0],$F[2],$F[-1]].join("/")' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
command to generate list of pathnames | while read path; do 
  IFS=/
  set -- $path
  echo "http://$3/$5"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you're starting out at `www/..`

```
pushd www
find * -type f | while read line; do echo http://${line%%/*}/${line##*/}; done
popd
```